# Systemd ordering: after multi-user.target before getty.target?

Tags: systemd, init, getty

I have an installer which I turned into a systemd service it needs,

- `networking.target` to be online
- `multi-user.target` to be online

I want my installer service to run after the above but **before** `getty.target` and `console-getty.service`. This is because I do not want the console to spam for a login before the installer is complete.

However, my distro (Centos 7) specifies a dependency on `multi-user.target` to `getty.target`,

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/getty.target
```

This means I can't put my service between the two, because my service will then be

- Dependent on `multi-user.target`
- Which is dependent on `getty.target`
- While my service is specified to BEFORE `getty.target`, and AFTER `multi-user.target`

What should I do given my needs here? Is there a way to do this by customizing `/etc` without mucking with `/usr/lib` so it's safe with the distro?

Comment: it looks like that if you're running a graphical environment you could use that target instead of getty https://www.osradar.com/understand-runlevels-or-targets-in-linux/

Comment: @Valentino I'm not running a graphical target.

Comment: Then maybe try and build your own target? I wouldn't be able to help you with the details but that might be your solution